# ElasticSearch filter boosting based on field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query:

```
{
"from": 0, 
"query": {
    "custom_filters_score": {
        "filters": [
            {
                "boost": 1.5, 
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "format": "test1"
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "boost": 1.5, 
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "format": "test2"
                    }
                }
            }
        ], 
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "query_string": {
                        "analyzer": "query_default", 
                        "fields": [
                            "title^5", 
                            "description^2", 
                            "indexable_content"
                        ], 
                        "query": "blah"
                    }
                }, 
                "should": []
            }
        }
    }
}, 
"size": 50
}
```

Which should be boosting things that have `{"format":"test1"}` in them, if I'm reading the documentation correctly.

However, using `explain` tells me that `"custom score, no filter match, product of:"` is the outcome, and the score of the returned documents that match the filter isn't changed by this filter.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: here's the schema:

```
mapping:
  edition:
    _all: { enabled: true }
    properties:
      title:       { type: string, index: analyzed }
      description: { type: string, index: analyzed }
      format:      { type: string, index: not_analyzed, include_in_all: false }
      section:     { type: string, index: not_analyzed, include_in_all: false }
      subsection:  { type: string, index: not_analyzed, include_in_all: false }
      subsubsection:  { type: string, index: not_analyzed, include_in_all: false }
      link:        { type: string, index: not_analyzed, include_in_all: false }
      indexable_content: { type: string, index: analyzed }
```

and let's assume a typical document is like:

```
{
    "format": "test1",
    "title": "blah",
    "description": "blah",
    "indexable_content": "keywords here",
    "section": "section",
    "subsection": "child-section",
    "link":"/section/child-section/blah"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it says "no filter match", it means that it didn't match any filters in your query. Most likely reason for this is that the records that match your query don't have terms "test1" in them. Unfortunately, you didn't provide mapping and test data, so it's difficult to tell what's going on there for sure.

Try running this query to see if you can actually find any records that match your search criteria and should be boosted:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "query_string": {
                    "analyzer": "query_default",
                    "fields": ["title^5", "description^2", "indexable_content"],
                    "query": "blah"
                }
            }, {
                "term": {
                    "format": "test1"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "size": 50
}
```

Your query looks fine and based on the provided information, it should work: https://gist.github.com/4448954

Comment: I've updated my question to include the schema and an redacted example document, if that changes anything.

Comment: I have updated the gist with information that you provided. It still works. I tested it with 0.20.2. So, I would guess you either redacted some important piece of information or you are using some old version of elasticsearch where this functionality is broken. Could you create a full repro that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Turns out I was an idiot and the indexes hadn't loaded. The query did work after all!